# Using XPathNavigator after disposing of StringReader

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, idisposable

Cant seem to find a definite answer.

I am wondering if after initializing a XPathDocument with a StringReader and getting a XPathNavigator will I get errors if I use the Navigator after I dispose of the StringReader?

Here is an example.

```
XPathDocument doc = null;
XPathNavigator nav = null;

using (var reader = new StringReader(config))
{
    doc = new XPathDocument(reader);
    nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
    nav.MoveToFirstChild();
}

var test = nav.SelectSingleNode("testNode");
```

If I continue to use this nav object will I get an error since the reader will have been disposed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to continue to use nav. All StringReader does is read a config file, which gets passed to your XPathDocument doc. After that it's job is done, it's data has all been used.